# Utility to take daily screenshots of a webpage

Tags: automation, screenshot, webpage, timer

I would like to have a visual history of my [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) bandwidth graphs, so that I can roughly/manually correlate them with some other factors.  Tomato can squirrel away the actual data points, but I'd rather not deal with importing it into some visualization tool.  For sheer simplicity, a single image per day would be preferable.

I'd like a program that can wake up at say, midnight, take a screenshot of a given webpage (the URL will always be the same), and save that image to a folder, maybe named after the date/time.  I'd prefer OS X, but Windows and Linux are fair game too; I use all three.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Your graphs link just gives me "Forbidden."

Answer (score 1):

Is this something you can do with Automator actions. You can use iCal to set autmator off running an action at regular intervals and there are plenty of different actions for taking screenshots of various sorts out there.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't a cron entry using wget suffice?

Something like...

```
DATE=`date +"%Y%m%d"`
mkdir /path/to/somewhere/snapshot.$DATE && \
  cd /path/to/somewhere/snapshot.$DATE && \
  wget -p -k http://your.url.here
```

Schedule this to execute once per day - you can then spawn your browser and read results from any day you want.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you don't mind the slight advertisement but I've started a site called [DailyScreenshot](http://dailyscreenshot.com) which does this exact thing.